# Brightness not working

Tags: 15.04, brightness

There are many answers out there for earlier versions but I did not have this problem before 15.04 and I know too little to judge, but I am guessing when I deduce that this problem is thus linked to 15.04 and other answers may not apply.

I can supply any logs or supplementary information if you tell me how to get them. Here are my specs to begin with:

[image: Specs]

Edit:

- Adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet splash` didn't work.
- Using `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5` did not work.

Very interesting non-related: Adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet splash` fixed my lengthy boot time problem, it used to take over 5 minutes to boot...

Comment: Did you try doing this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1979932 ?

Comment: @Raphael That didn't work but it lead me to another page, with a solution that looks promising, I'll restart and post the answer down below if it works. (Or is posting an answer to your own question a bad thing?)

Comment: Nah do whatever you like!

Comment: Adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the grub line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash` did not work.

Comment: Check whether you have graphics driver installed.
Sometimes it is the reason.

Comment: How do I do that? If you mean the NVidia driver, that is installed. I blacklisted the Nouveau driver though because it was slowing down my boot time considerably, could that be the reason?

Comment: I think that may be the reason. There is no harm in trying this! Try enabling it.. you can get other ways to make your boot faster. However graphics if enabled keeps running all the time, so eats up the battery.

Comment: I don't mind because I'm plugged in 24/7. I'm not sure I want to enable Nouveau, last time I had to re-install because of it. any other way? :P

Comment: Try following this however it is for ubuntu 13.10.     http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Comment: the solution on that site broke my pc, do you know how I can delete the .conf file from the GRUB BASH terminal?

Comment: I am not sure whether you can delete from minimal bash but you can try mounting the file system and delete the config file. However you can achieve that using Ubuntu live USB. Sorry that your system crashed.

Comment: No problem, I shouldn't have forced my system to use a driver I had purged. Forgot about that :P

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
3. Save the file & exit gedit.
4. Then type: `sudo update-grub`
5. Finally `sudo reboot`

Comment: Does that mean removing `quite splash` or just adding it to the end?

Comment: remove quite splash

Comment: Didn't work. You sure it's `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` and not `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` I have to modify?

Comment: Have you tried both?